# Insertion sort implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Comparable;


class InsertionSort {
    private InsertionSort() {}

    private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w) {
        return (v.compareTo(w) < 0);
    }

    private static void exch(Object[] a, int i, int j) {
        Object swap = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = swap;
    }

    private static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
        int length = a.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            // Maintain Invariant
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                if (less(a[j], a[j - 1])) { // Invariant broken, fix it.
                    exch(a, j, j - 1);
                }
            }
        }
        // Postcondition: assert isSorted(a) 
    }

    private static void show(Object[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

    private static Integer[] readAllInts() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numberOfItems;
        Integer[] items;
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            numberOfItems = scanner.nextInt();
            items = new Integer[numberOfItems];         
        } else {
            // mybe throw an error?
            return new Integer[0];
        }

        int i = 0;
        while(scanner.hasNext() && i < numberOfItems) {
            items[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        return items;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] items = InsertionSort.readAllInts();
        InsertionSort.sort(items);
        InsertionSort.show(items);
    }
}
```

Above is the implementation of the insertion sort algorithm. I want learn how to write algorithms as well [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.in/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882). Now below are the points which I have taken care of or am concerned about.

- Kept meaningful names.
- Declared variables near their usage.
- Suppose, this code needs to consumed by many clients then where and what exception I should handle and throw.
- Kept variable scopes to as local as possible for easy GC.
- Most of the methods are static because I don't think they belong to a particular object.

That's it for now, I will keep updating the list if something comes to me later.

Ref: [Algorithms](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/21elementary/Insertion.java.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `readAllInts`

This is a wishy washy name. What does it mean, "all ints"? In the universe? In my little black book of ints? Entered by the user on standard input? Aha!

It might be good to split this up to multiple methods:

- a method to read and return the number of ints from a scanner and handle errors: print a message in case of invalid input and try again, or simply throw an exception
- a method to read specified number of ints from a scanner and return as an array
- a method that calls the previous two and returns the array

That way each method will have a simpler, single responsibility.

A bigger problem with this method is that it doesn't belong in the InsertionSort class. The way you read an array of integers has nothing to do with the spring algorithm.

#### Type safety

By not using type tokens, you sacrificed type safety. For example a call `less(4, "hello")` would compile, which is undesirable.

You should never use bare types, always specify type parameters.
For example you can make `less` type safe like this:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean less(T v, T w) {
    return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
}
```

This effectively prevents `less(4, "hello")` at compile time.

Correcting `sort` similarly:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[] a) {
    int length = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (less(a[j], a[j - 1])) { // Invariant broken, fix it.
                exch(a, j, j - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it, the other methods are fine,
as they don't use bare types, and they are fine using `Object[]` for swapping and printing.

#### Naming

`exch` is not a great name. " exchange " would be better, but the most common name for this operation is "swap".

`less` is also not great, as some might interpret it in the sense of " minus ". I suggest "lessThan" instead, which makes the comparison logic perfectly clear.

The variable `a` is the worst offender of all. "swap" is not great either.

Answer (score 2):

### Speed up the sort

Here in the main part of your sort:

> ```
>    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
>         // Maintain Invariant
>         for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
>             if (less(a[j], a[j - 1])) { // Invariant broken, fix it.
>                 exch(a, j, j - 1);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Once you find the correct spot for `a[i]`, you should immediately move on to the next item.  Right now you swap it down to the correct spot and then keep looking at all the other items that are already sorted.  So I would add a `break` statement like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Maintain Invariant
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (less(a[j], a[j - 1])) { // Invariant broken, fix it.
                exch(a, j, j - 1);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that its not a one time process. We need to keep exchanging until we maintain the invariant that all the items to the left of `i` should be sorted.

Comment: You are saying that once a exchange has been done you will pop out of the inner loop but that is not correct. You may have to do multiple exchanges.

Comment: @CodeYogi I said "once you swap it down the the correct spot" meaning multiple swaps.  What I am saying is that the moment the item is greater than the one to its left (after potentially multiple swaps have been made), you no longer have to continue the inner loop.  That's what the `break` I added does.

Comment: Ah! I see you are right. I think its similar to:
```java

    for (int j = i; j > 0 && less(a[j], a[j - 1]); j++) {
        exch(a, j, j - 1);
    }

```

Comment: @CodeYogi Yes, that would be a more compact way to express the same thing.